# How to define secure key for browserstack in accespance.suite.yml file in codeception

Tags: php, continuous-integration, travis-ci, codeception, browserstack

I am trying to run my test using TravisCI with browserstack add-on.
Test cases are written in codeception.

Now, I am able to successfully define a secure key in travis.yml for browserstack addon but acceptance.suite.yml file also requires a username and access key under capabilities. How to define that value in a secure format in a similar way we defined in travis.yml?

The reference document also shows username and access key used in the plain text in host url. But I need those values in secure from.

One thing I can do it by creating env variable in travis file but I dont understand how do I access those variables? Each time it gaves me an error -

**[Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException] Invalid username or password**

Below is my add-on setting for Browserstack in Travis file.

```
addons:   browserstack:
    username: "username"
    access_key:
        secure: "secure-key"
```

Now, acceptance.suite.yml file also needs the credential but I need to keep those secret.

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\Acceptance
        - WPWebDriver
    config:
          WPWebDriver:
            host: 'hub-cloud.browserstack.com'
            port: 80
            browser: 'firefox'
            url: 'http://localtest.me'
            adminUsername: ''
            adminPassword: ''
            adminPath: '/wp-admin'
            capabilities:
               'browserstack.user': 'username'
               'browserstack.key': 'I NEED SECURE KEY HERE'
              'os': 'OS X'
              'os_version': 'sierra'
              'browserstack.debug': 'true'
              'build': 'Build_01'
              'project': 'Automated_1'
              'browserstack.local': 'true'
```

Any help would appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figure out the way to access the env var.

Using the **Dynamic Configuration with parameters**

If you are using env var then you need to declare env section in codeception.yml file. Add below line in codeception.yml file.

> params:
>
> ```
> - env
> ```

Now, we need to access the env var for Browserstack in out acceptance.suite.yml file.

> capabilities:
>
> ```
>           'browserstack.user': 'username'
>           'browserstack.key': '%BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY%'
> ```

Comment: [Link to Dynamic Configuration with parameters documentation](http://codeception.com/docs/06-ModulesAndHelpers#Dynamic-Configuration-With-Params)